# How to fill plotted graph in python with simbol (it can be text '#' or '*)

Tags: python, numpy

**I have done python code to draw the heart and stuck when i comes to fill this graph with text.**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
plt.title('Heart', fontsize=24)

y = np.sqrt(1-np.power(x, 2))+np.power(np.square(x), 1/3)
y1= -np.sqrt(1-np.power(x, 2))+np.power(np.square(x), 1/3)
plt.plot(x, y, 'b')
plt.plot(x, y1, 'b')
my_x_ticks = np.arange(-2, 2.5, 0.5)
my_y_ticks = np.arange(-2, 2.5, 0.5)
plt.xticks(my_x_ticks)
plt.yticks(my_y_ticks)
plt.fill_between(x, y, y1,color="red",alpha=0.9)
plt.grid(False)`enter code here`
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood correctly you want to put a text field on your plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
plt.title('Heart', fontsize=24)

y = np.sqrt(1-np.power(x, 2))+np.power(np.square(x), 1/3)
y1 = -np.sqrt(1-np.power(x, 2))+np.power(np.square(x), 1/3)
plt.plot(x, y, 'b')
plt.plot(x, y1, 'b')

# this is your text; first argument is x-coordinate, second argument y-coordinate
plt.text(0, 0, "My Text", fontsize=18, color="r", va="center", ha="center", backgroundcolor="w")

my_x_ticks = np.arange(-2, 2.5, 0.5)
my_y_ticks = np.arange(-2, 2.5, 0.5)
plt.xticks(my_x_ticks)
plt.yticks(my_y_ticks)
plt.fill_between(x, y, y1, color="red",alpha=0.9)
plt.grid(False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: yes, you are right. it can be anything like '#' or '*' or any symbol is okay

Comment: You added text="My Text" in center of graph but can we add sign like '#" in all over graph (inside graph boundaries)

Comment: like this: https://images4.programmersought.com/812/6e/6eeebb107c34602219a5e611d6a5cd54.png

Comment: According to the [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html) you can use the `hatch` argument to apply the following symbols: `{'/', '\', '|', '-', '+', 'x', 'o', 'O', '.', '*'}`

Example: `plt.fill_between(x, y, y1, hatch="*", facecolor="red", edgecolor="blue", alpha=0.9)` which [looks like this](https://imgur.com/fN5bOQi)

Comment: No problem. As you're new - please accept & check my answer as useful/right so others can benefit from it aswell